# NodeJS Modules export array of items instantiated by a class

Tags: arrays, node.js, class, node-modules

In NodeJS, I am instantiating two objects from two different classes, putting them into an array, and then mapping through them with Array.map. If I do this all in one file, it works fine. However, if I create the objects in a different file and export/require the array, it comes in undefined.

```
//code from file ClassA.js:

exports.ClassA = class ClassA {
    constructor(name) {       
        this.name = name;
    }
}

//code from file ClassB.js

exports.ClassB = class ClassB {
    constructor(name) {       
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This way works:

```
//code from file index.js
const { ClassA } = require("./ClassA");
const { ClassB } = require("./ClassB");

const myClassItem1 = new ClassA('Class A Item');
const myClassItem2 = new ClassB('Class B Item');

const myArray = [];
myArray.push(myClassItem1, myClassItem2);

console.log('array', myArray); //returns: [ ClassA { name: 'Class A Item' }, ClassB { name: 'Class B Item' } ]
console.log(myArray.map(item => item.name)); //returns: [ 'Class A Item', 'Class B Item' ]
```

//Separating out the item instantiation into a different file does not

```
//code from file items.js
const { ClassA } = require("./ClassA");
const { ClassB } = require("./ClassB");

const myClassItem1 = new ClassA('Class A Item');
const myClassItem2 = new ClassB('Class B Item');

const myArray = [];
myArray.push(myClassItem1, myClassItem2);

console.log(myArray); //returns: [ ClassA { name: 'Class A Item' }, ClassB { name: 'Class B Item' } ]

exports.myArray;

//code from file index.js
const { myArray } = require('./items');

console.log(myArray); //returns undefined
console.log(myArray.map(item => item.name)) //throws error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
exports.myArray;
```

which does nothing; it references a non-existent property on `exports`, and that's it. You need to explicitly assign to a property of the `exports` object, so that when the file is `require`d elsewhere, you can use property lookup on the `require`d object to get the value you need:

```
exports.myArray = myArray;
```

and then

```
const { myArray } = require('./items');
```

will retrieve the array as desired.

You could also avoid the standalone variable entirely, which would probably make things clearer:

```
exports.myArray = [myClassItem1, myClassItem2];
```